# JAX-WS MTOM streaming: server reads entire stream before sending

Tags: java, streaming, jax-ws, mtom

I have a JAX-WS RI server that does MTOM streaming. From the client, everything is fine. The server receives a StreamingDataHandler, and neither side uses much memory sending 1 GB. Retrieving the file, however, the server is reading the entire contents before sending it. The client is OK. I'm using DataHandler on both ends, so that aspect of things is fine. I just don't want the server to read all the data from the InputStream before it starts sending. I have the following annotations on the impl:

```
@MTOM
@StreamingAttachment(parseEagerly = false, memoryThreshold = 1L)
@WebService(...)
```

I've tried `parseEagerly` `true` and `false`. I set the memory threshold low because I'm not concerned about small performance hits for small files.

Is this a bug with JAX-WS RI?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did.  Worked like a charm.

**Interface** (think it's a lot like what you did)

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface ResultsServer {    
    @WebMethod
    @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream")
    public DataHandler getResultDataAsXML(@WebParam Integer raceId) throws Exception;
}
```

**Implementation**

```
@MTOM
@WebService(endpointInterface = "ca.sportstats.wtc.ResultsServer")
@StreamingAttachment(parseEagerly=true, memoryThreshold=4000000L)
public class ResultsServerImpl implements ResultsServer {

    @Override
    public DataHandler getResultDataAsXML(@WebParam Integer raceId) throws Exception {
        File xmlFile = new File("c:/tmp/xml/response.xml");
        //... write my xml file using an XMLStreamWriter
        return new DataHandler(new FileDataSource(xmlFile));
    }
}
```

**Testing**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

       URL url = new URL("http://url/to/ipmlementation/ResultsServerImplService?wsdl");
       QName qname = new QName("http://test.test.com/", "ResultsServer");

       Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
       ResultsServerImpl resultServer = service.getPort(ResultsServerImpl.class);

       /************  test download  ***************/
       DataHandler handler = resultServer.getResultDataAsXML(4);
       StreamingDataHandler dh = (StreamingDataHandler) handler;
       File file = File.createTempFile("test-received.xml", "");
       dh.moveTo(file);
       dh.close();

    }
}
```

This worked for me to stream (from the server) a large XML file without reading it all in memory.

**See also**

- https://metro.java.net/guide/ch06.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/web.1111/e13734/mtom.htm#i279618
- http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-attachment-with-mtom/

Comment: I'm using weblogic 12c, same implementation as above. Attachment is sent as an base64encoded string, not as an attachment... This worked perfect on 11g. What environment did you use for this?